# Can we hide the submenu in the new navigation?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, new-nav

Now, the new navigation is in alpha test. One of the reasons why we change the navigation is that we want to make it easy for inexperienced users to find the right place to either read, answer or moderate. I like the three tabs in the new navigation which are "new", "popular" and "need answer". But I think the submenu under the three tabs is an interference and it makes the navigation complicated.

Can we hide the submenu in the new navigation? The submenu is hidden and only the three tabs are visible on the page. When the user wants to change the rule of the three tabs, he/she can click something (need to design) to make the submenu visible.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This section of UX has been redesigned since the question was asked. That said, we don't have any plans at the moment for allowing the auto-filter options/sub-menu to be hidden by the user.